# Differentiable Operator Continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space $C^{\infty}[a,b]$ with norm $||f|| = max_{[0,1]} |f(x)|$, with $f\in C^{\infty}[a,b]$. Is the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ continuous on $C^{\infty}[a,b]$?

I'm very confused because it seems almost trivial-- there are plenty of examples of the derivative not being a continuous operator-- that's why it's so hard to study.. but in this space, isn't it defined to be only those functions whose derivatives are infinitely differentiable? How do I show this formally?

Comment: Please do not deface your question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you don't want just the sup norm on smooth functions. Rather, topologize smooth functions by the family of seminorms given by sups of all derivatives. (This is a Frechet space, the projective limit topology on the Banach spaces $C^k[a,b]$ with sum of sups of derivatives up to order $k$.) Differentiation is continuous in that topology. (And differentiation is continuous from $C^k[a,b]$ to $C^{k-1}[a,b]$.)

A reason to understand that just the sup norm of values is not the right topology on smooth functions is that the space is not complete in that topology.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f_n(x) = \sin(n \pi x)$. $||f_n|| = 1$, but $df_n/dx$ is unbounded.